# How to use Google Compute engine with my own domain?

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine

I found these instructions but they are not very clear:

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

1. I am using Namecheap. Will I need to specify my own Host Record on namecheap? If so How do I determine the IP address to enter for my A recordy type?
2. If setting up the host record on namecheap is not an option, where do I do this using google Public-DNS?
3. I'm simply trying to get my domain http://www.example.com to resolve.

---

Responding to "Close" votes: This has 2 helpful votes below, and over 500 views. This question is relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Assign a static ip address to your compute engine VM instance (static IP address is free as long as it is in use)
- Install apache on the instance.
- At namecheap, create your 'A record' or host record for hostname 'www' that points to this static ip address.
- Open the http port so that the instance can start serving

done.

Comment: I tried the same thing with a bitnami tomcat VM, and the redirect works fine when it is unmasked. How can I get to work with a masked redirect? I have been getting an error "site does not permit cross-origin framing."

Comment: Static IP is free as long as the instance is active. If instance is stopped, static IP is billed.

Comment: Yes, the platform is constantly evolving... . Updated.

Comment: Search for external IP addresses to assign static IP address to the compute engine.